# How to solve error : No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it?

Tags: laravel, redis, environment-variables, laravel-5.3

In file `.env`, I change`CACHE_DRIVER=file` to be `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`. Then I access my system, there exist error like this :

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hmm cant be a firewall issue because your redis host is localhost. Are you sure redis is running on localhost? You can possibly check with `redis-cli ping` (you should get a pong)

Comment: Is local server running??

Comment: If on Windows, run `netstat -aon | more` and check what is happening on tcp://127.0.0.1:6379.  That's a start.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether `redis` is running or not.

Run this command see are you getting the reponse as `PONG`.

```
redis-cli ping
```

Also if you recently changed the `.env` file, make sure to restart your laravel server and clear the laravel caches

***to clear cache***

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

***to clear config cache***

```
php artisan config:clear
```